# Google search translates my site to Japanese

Tags: google-search, google-translate

When I do a search through google for my companies site, the results for the site come back as Japanese. When I look at the cache they have of the site it shows that it is in Japanese and when I translate it, it just returns the text as Lorem Ipsum. The site is in English and the "lang" tag is is set to en-US. I have posted to the google help forum, but have not heard anything about what I can do. This only happens through a google search, both Yahoo and Bing return results that are in English. Can anybody help me with this or guide in the right direction?

This is the site:
[rbcompany](http://www.rbcompany.com/)

and here is a link to the google search:
[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=googgle%20cache&oq=goog&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i59l2j69i60l2.2237j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=r%26b%20company)